# Storing float data type in NModbus SlaveDataStore - InputRegisters

Tags: c#, modbus, datastore, slave

I am writing a modbus tcp/ip slave simulator using NModbus and I observe that the datastore present for the nmodbus slave only supports ushort data type. Is there any way to write float or decimal values in the datastore provided by nmodbus slave?

I am trying to use this datastore so that I can use it to read data from Input registers in my modbus tcp/ip master program which is written seperately.

I've looked in the NModbus source code (https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/blob/develop/NModbus/Data/DefaultSlaveDataStore.cs) specifically into data store class. However, I observe that it only supports ushort types.

Below is an code that I am using while writing data to modbus slave input registers in my modbus tcp/ip slave.

```
public void WriteDefaultValuesToModbusSlave()
        {
            // create and start the TCP slave
            StartTcpListener();

            var factory = new ModbusFactory();
            var network = factory.CreateSlaveNetwork(_slaveTcpListener);
            IModbusSlave slave = factory.CreateSlave(_slaveId);

            // _floatValues =   0F, 2F, 4F, 6F, 8F, 10F
            byte[][] data = RegisterFunctions.FloatToByteValueArrays(_floatValues, 32);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (byte[] byteArray in data)
            {
                _littleEndianValues[i] = Endian.LittleEndian(byteArray);
                i++;
            }

            ushort[] ushortArray = RegisterFunctions.ByteValueArraysToUShorts(_littleEndianValues);
            slave.DataStore.InputRegisters.WritePoints(0, ushortArray);
            network.AddSlave(slave);

            // Start listening
            var listenTask = network.ListenAsync();
        }
```

If anyone has experience working with NModbus and creating a datastore for a modbus tcp/ip slave which can be used as data for reading input registers. Please let me know how can this be achieved?

Comment: The bus is 16 bits so any larger data you must read multiple times to get value.  So in c# you must split the two 16 bits into an array of 4 bytes and then use BitConverter.  Very simple.

Comment: @jdweng : That's helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what you can do, depending upon the range of values you need is read/write the values multiplied by a power of 10 and then divide by that same power of 10 when you display it.  You can combine this with casting to/from an INT16 to get negative values.  Most building automation systems that we integrate with seem to support this so I believe it is common practice.

For instance if you needed to return the value of a water temperature in Celsius with 2 digits of precision:

1) A UINT16 has the range 0...65535 so you could get temperature values 0.00 to 655.35 by multiplying the value by 100 for the input register and dividing it by 100 when you use it in a calculation or display it.

2) An INT16 has the range -32768...32767 so you could get values -327.68 to 327.67 by multiplying the value by 100 and casting it to a UINT16 for the input register and then casting back to an INT16 and dividing by 100 when you use it in a calculation or display it.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but can be a good solution.